# Ajax username availability check not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net MVC 4 and jQuery 1.9.1 to check username availability when user inputs the username in textfield. For some reason I'm getting `Internal Server Error 500` in my browser console.

Here is my code:

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult chkPrevUser(string username)
    {
        var prevUser = rentdb.Regs.Where(p => p.username == username).FirstOrDefault();

        if (prevUser.username == username)
        {
            return Json(false);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtUsername").keyup(function () {
            var name = $("#txtUsername").val();
            var status = $("#userStatus");
            var user = $.trim(name);
            if (user.length > 3) {
                status.html("Checking....")
                $.post("/Home/chkPrevUser", { username: name },
                            function (data) {
                                if (data == true) {
                                    status.html("<font color=green>'<b>" + name + "</b>' is available!</font>");
                                } else {
                                    status.html("<font color=red>'<b>" + name + "</b>' is not available!</font>");
                                }
                            });
            } else {
                status.html("Need more characters...");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.username, new { id = "txtUsername" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.username)
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code? How can I solve this issue and check if username exists already by ajax?

Comment: Is there any reason your not using a `[Remote]` attribute? You error is most likely because `prevUser` is null (no match was found) so `prevUser.username` throws an exception. You can confirm this by inspecting the response (Network tab of your browser tools)

Comment: And `if (prevUser.username == username)` really makes so sense since your getting the object with `p => p.username == username` - instead you should just check `if (prevUser == null) { return Json(false); } else { return Json(true); }`

Comment: It also makes no sense to be calling this on `keyup()` - your making an unnecessary call to the server which will always return false (once the code is corrected) until the user has actually finished typing the user name (and as a result displaying a meaningless error message).

Comment: Thanks for your awesome tips @StephenMuecke, I admit that was stupid of me! You could post your tips as an answer if you want.

Comment: About `keyup()`, what will I use instead of `keyup()` after user has finished typing?

Comment: Will add an answer with more detail shortly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `500 (Internal Server Error)` is thrown because your query

```
var prevUser = rentdb.Regs.Where(p => p.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
```

will return `null` of no match is found, so your following line of code

```
if (prevUser.username == username)
```

will throw a `NullReferenceException` because you cannot access the `username` property of `null`

Change the code to

```
if (prevUser == null)
{
    return Json(false);
}
else
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

However I recommend that you delete your script and instead use a `RemoteAttribute`, which would applied to you property as

```
[Remote("chkPrevUser", ErrorMessage = "The user name already exists")]
public string username { get; set; }
```

The controller method just needs to be changed to `[HttpGet]` and the return statements changed to add the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter (e.g. `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`). For more information, refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

If however you choose to keep your script, I suggest the following changes

1. Handle the `.change()` event rather than `.keyup()`. Currently if
   the user was trying to enter a 10 character user name, an
   unnecessary call is made to server on the 4th through to 9th
   characters which would return an annoying and meaningless error
   message. Note the `RemoteAttribute` initially handles the `.change()` event (i.e. validation is not performed until the user tabs out of the textbox), and if its invalid, then handles the `.keyup()` event if the user makes an edit.
2. Use `'@Url.Action("chkPrevUser", "Home")'` instead of
   `"/Home/chkPrevUser"` to ensure your url's are always correctly
   generated

Answer (score 0):

Server Error 500 means the server throws an exception in most of the times. Debug your method and see what cause the exception.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote] attribute should work like a charm on this. Try these steps , it worked for my Application.

1) Viewmodel Class in Model folder

```
[Remote("IsAlreadySigned", "User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists in database. Try another Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
```

2) Create these 2 Action in User Controller.

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult IsAlreadySigned(string Username)
        {

            return Json(IsUserAvailable(Username));

        }
        public bool IsUserAvailable(string UserN)
        {
            // Assume these details coming from database  
            List<UserVM> RegisterUsers = new List<UserVM>()
        {

            new UserVM {Username = UserN }

        };
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {


                var UserId = db.User.Where(x => x.Username == UserN).Select(x => new { UserN }).FirstOrDefault();

                bool status;
                if (UserId != null)
                {
                    //Already registered  
                    status = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Available to use  
                    status = true;
                }


                return status;
            }
        }
```

3) Create new View "Signup" with UserVM class Model.

Now, try and you will see error as soon as you tab out from Username field in Signup form.